# Combinations of a vector of pointers using primary and secondary keys

Tags: c++, vector, compare, permutation

Hi I need to loop through all the possible combinations of a vector of pointers,
I tried something but it doesn't give all the combinations (I sorted the Vector first)

I first created a pointer comparator :

```
struct PointerCompare {
    bool operator()(const int* l, const int* r) {
        return *l < *r;
    }
};
```

The problem is that my pointers may have the same values, so to show you the problem, all my pointers will have the same value

```
int main() {
    vector<int*> myValues(4);

    for (vector<int*>::iterator it = myValues.begin(); it != myValues.end(); ++it) {
        *it = new int(0);
    }


    std::sort(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), PointerCompare());

    do {
        for (vector<int*>::iterator it = myValues.begin(); it != myValues.end(); ++it) {
            cout << ' ' << **it;
        }
        cout << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(),PointerCompare()));

    myValues.clear();
}
```

So I first sorted the `vector` and then asked for permutations using the same comparator.
Everything is fine with this when the values are different.

So the result of my test is : `0 0 0`
and not 6 times (`3!`) : `0 0 0` (that is what he should give me since I ask for permutation of the pointers and not the values)

My thought is, when two pointers `l` and `r` have the same value, `l.compare(r)` returns false, and `r.compare(l)` also, so he doesn't swap them in next permutation if needed.
In that case I should expand my comparator when the pointers have the same value, maybe the address of the pointers.
Am I right in all this? How should I compare pointers?

**EDIT : This is just an example to show you the issue (which is I am trying to get all possible permutations of a vector of pointers), what I am saying is that there is a problem with this when there is two or more pointers that point to the same value. eg :
p1 points to 1, p2 points to 2, p3 points to 1 :
I would like to have all these combinations :
p1 p2 p3, p1 p3 p2, p2 p1 p3, p2 p3 p1, p3 p2 p1, p3 p1 p2
But that is not what I get, since he "confuses" p1 and p3**

Comment: So if the vector consists of four zeros, what output do you want to see?

Comment: It's not a vector of zeros, it's a vector of pointers to zeros, if it's the case, I would want to see 24 times this 0 0 0 0

Comment: Can you explain what is not clear with my question ??

Answer (score 1):

You may use a intermediate array if you want duplicated permutation:

```
void print_combination(const std::vector<int*>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(v.size());
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0u);

    do {
        for (auto index : indexes) {
            std::cout << ' ' << *v[index];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    } while (std::next_permutation(indexes.begin(), indexes.end()));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Grk3Ty)

Comment: You probably didn't get my issue, the issue is that I am using a vector of pointers ... I don't ask for duplicated permutation

Comment: @Othman: Note that the indirection solves your issue. But to compare pointer you can use default comparator (`std::less<int*>`) [Live demo](https://ideone.com/4x6SgR)

Comment: I would like to compare the pointers but depending on their values

Comment: Your demo is quite what I need, I want the permutations to be ordered too, like this : 1 1 3, 1 1 3(this is not a duplication), 1 3 1,  .... 3 1 1

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator compares the values, not the pointers. You should check if `l < r`, not `*l < *r`.

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: But you can use `std::less<T*>`.

Comment: @icepack, that was my thought, since my comparator doesn't give an perfect order to pointers ( when they have same value ), so I may have to add some other comparison when the pointers have the same value, which could be comparing the addresses

Comment: @AntonSavin Your example contains the original comparator. And I still don't see how my suggestion causes undefined behavior

Comment: @AntonSavin sorry I forgot to add the instruction that sorts the elements first, the vector must be sorted to get all the permutations, try this now http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @icepack my example didn't use original comparator, it used `std::less`. With it and pre-sorted vector it works. You can't compare any two pointers using bare `<`, read carefully the standard chapter I referenced above.

Comment: @AntonSavin The chapter defines comparing of pointers to objects. The clauses there are all well-defined and, more important, irrelevant to the case here where the comparison is between 2 pointers to `int`. Moreover, look at the implementation of `std::less` - it decays to simple pointer comparison for `int*`.

Comment: @icepack you're right, I found the answer using yours, I will post it

Comment: @icepack `int` is also an object, see [intro.object]/1. Implementation of `std::less` doesn't really matter.

Comment: @AntonSavin I've reviewed the expr.rel chapter. The behavior that you refer to is in sub-paragraph 2, not 3. However, it seems to be changed in the ongoing draft of C++: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

Comment: @icepack no, I'm referring to sub-paragraph 3, and nothing changed in N4296, nor even in N4431. The pointers allocated with `new` don't belong to the same array, nor they point to subobjects of one object, so comparison for them is undefined.

Comment: N3337 [expr.rel]/**2**: — "*If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same
object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results
of p<q, p>q, p<=q, and p>=q are unspecified*". This chapter has been removed from N4296.

Comment: @AntonSavin We have instead: "*The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on operands of arithmetic or enumeration type. If both operands are pointers, pointer conversions (4.10) and qualification conversions (4.4) are performed to bring them to their composite pointer type (Clause 5). After conversions, the operands shall have the same type*"... Clause 5: "*If both operands (after conversions) are of arithmetic or enumeration type, each of the operators shall yield
true if the specified relationship is true and false if it is false.*"

Comment: @icepack so both operands are pointers to `int`, and they are converted to their composite pointer type which is `int*` (no conversion is actually needed of course)

Comment: @AntonSavin Yes, and sub-paragraph 3 doesn't define such comparison

Comment: @icepack Sub-paragraph 3 defines conditions when comparison for pointers is defined, and the results of such comparison. Sorry, further discussion is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, using the answer of icepack, the problem with my comparator is that, it doesn't give a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) to the set, because the computer can't decide the order of two pointers with same pointed value, 
I changed my comparator to this :

```
struct PointerCompare {
          bool operator()(const int* l, const int* r) {

              if(*l==*r)
                  return (l<r);
              return (*l<*r);
          }
        };
```

With this I have a total order, here is the result of [my example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fc5cd21dd227d4a) of 0 0 0

[other example with some different values](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f779793940d6c6bf)

Comment: What you're doing is formally called primary and secondary keys. Your primary key is the pointed value and your secondary key (which is used only if primary key isn't enough) is the pointer.

Comment: @icepack ok, I didn't know that, I'll put it on the title